Why is my NextJS project failing to deploy on Vercel when it builds fine locally?
I'm deploying a full-stack NextJS project to Vercel for the first time. I use typescript (partially), sass, prisma, as some of the main libraries. When building locally, everything works fine. However, when deploying to Vercel, the build logs suggest it's successful but then going to the URL reveals that it hasn't worked.
It first seemed like none of the styling occurred (i.e. sass wasn't transpiling? correctly). However, I don't think this is the case as some components have styling.
When attempting to navigate to a different page, the page doesn't change. In fact, I can go to any route e.g. '[domain]/blah' and it'll take me to the same broken page.
Any ideas why this might be? Very lost at the moment and not sure of my next steps. I am getting some console errors but can't find out where the missing '<' would be.
Broken (what I see on vercel deployment)

Expected (what I see locally after npm run build & npm start)

Build summary

Config Files
Here are some code snippets of my config files
next.config.mjs
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
 
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);
 
/**
* @type {import('next').NextConfig}
*/
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  sassOptions: {
    includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'styles')],
  },
};
 
export default nextConfig;

vercel.json
{
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "package.json",
      "use": "@vercel/next",
      "config": {
        "includeFiles": [
          "prisma/**"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "/"
    }
  ]
}

tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ]
    },
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "noEmit": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "strictNullChecks": true
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}

package.json
{
  "name": "chex_map_app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "prisma generate && next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "format": "prettier --write ./**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,css,md,json} --list-different --config ./.prettierrc.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^5.12.1",
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "jose": "^5.2.4",
    "mapbox-gl": "^3.2.0",
    "next": "14.1.2",
    "prisma": "^5.12.1",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-map-gl": "^7.1.7",
    "uuidv4": "^6.2.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@playwright/test": "^1.42.1",
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.6",
    "@types/node": "^20.12.2",
    "@types/react": "18.2.79",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.1.2",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.1",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^16.6.2",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.34.1",
    "prettier": "^3.2.5",
    "sass": "^1.72.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18.17.0",
    "npm": ">=9.6.0"
  }
}


There is no need to build for deployment in Vercel. Just put your project in GitHub first and connect Vercel to it and it will automatically read the information from GitHub.

Turns out it was a routing issue. Vercel.json was overriding proper build settings. Also, cleared next.config.mjs as I think some styling issues were occurring with SASS. Working perfectly now!
